# HttpUtility is not recognized in my project

Tags: web-scraping

I try to write some basic CommandLine based HTML **scraper**

It is to be executed from a normal client *'dos'* CMD console, so its not on a server.
I have set the project to .net 4.0  (not the default client 4.0 but the full one).
But still i am unable to make use of the word "**HttpUtility**" as in **HttpUtility.UrlDecode(content);**

On visual studio 2010
I am using

```
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
```

I have set a file reference to the htmlagilitypack, but HTTPutility is just plain .net 4.0 and not recognized
What do i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

well i found the solution for it, make sure to add (manual) a reference to

System.Web

By default its not referenced in an console app, might be in an aspx app but not in an console like app. after adding it also as a reference it worked.